# How to set overrflow-x; visbile and overflow-y: scroll on the same div

Tags: html, css, rtd

I have a sidebar, that has some predefined classes, that I have to use. I cannot make other divs. I have to use those ones. The problem is I have a search input and a table of contents.

EXPECTED RESULT:
The table of contents should be scrollable.
The search dropdown shouldn't be cut by the div on the right(main content).

This is the parent div of both. Please do not say use 2 different divs. I cannot do that. I am constrainted for the time being by the theme.

```
.wy-nav-side {
    width: 40rem;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 95%;
}
```

ACTUAL RESULT:
The search dropdown is cut off, but the scroll is working. Here are some additional classes that are avaialble for TOC, and search, but they didn't work:

```
   .wy-menu-vertical {
        margin-left: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        height: 95%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .wy-side-scroll {
        width: 35rem;
        background-color: #fff;
        height: 95%;
        overflow: visible!important;
    }
```

```
<nav data-toggle="wy-nav-shift" class="wy-nav-side">
      <div class="wy-side-scroll">
        <div class="wy-side-nav-search">
            <a href="../index.html" class="icon icon-home"> 
            <img src="../_static/image.png" class="logo" alt="Logo">
          </a>
              <div class="version">
                2.3
              </div>   
<div id="searchbox" role="search">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg row pl-3">
      <span class="algolia-autocomplete algolia-autocomplete-left" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; direction: ltr;"><input type="text" class="form-control w-100 ds-input" name="q" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search the Docs" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="algolia-autocomplete-listbox-0" dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top;"><pre aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: pre; font-family: Lato, proxima-nova, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; word-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: normal; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; text-transform: none;">kub</pre><span class="ds-dropdown-menu ds-with-1" role="listbox" id="algolia-autocomplete-listbox-0" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; z-index: 100; left: 0px; right: auto; display: none;"><div class="ds-dataset-1"></div></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wy-menu wy-menu-vertical" data-spy="affix" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
              <p class="caption"><span class="caption-text">Contents</span></p>
<ul class="current">
<li>Lots of li's here</li>
</ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: please add html

Comment: I can add, but the HTML is generated on load time, by an external theme I cannot touch.

Comment: you can add sample code

Comment: Check the description. This is the part that I am talking about.

Comment: your code is working and height to `.wy-side-scroll`

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? `wy-side-scroll` has `height: 95%`. Do you want me to remove it? I had it like that originally. Without the first css block, `wy-nad-side`, but it didn't work..

Comment: put height in pixels

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191593/discussion-between-dimitris-efst-and-xenio-gracias).